# Prove $U(f,P')\le U(f,P)$ ($P'$ a refinement of $P$) with weird HINT

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

In Calculus, there is a theorem that a refinement of a partition will produces a smaller upper sum. The proof is easy, and I know it. However, I found a handout from my teacher, see the figure.

[image]

In (b), it seems a much more simpler version of the theorem I mentioned above, since the refinement only added one point. However, I totally can't get how to prove (b) **"from (a)"**. The hint said "**Consequently,**" which means it is a simple inference directly from the theorem in (a). (Right?) But how can one **use** (a) to prove (b)? I have been thinking it for 30 minutes, but still being confused.

Comment: It's a stupid hint, but if you really want to justify the lecturer, you can show that $R_{f;[a,b]}(\mathcal{P}',\Xi)-R_{f;[a,b]}(\mathcal{P},\Xi)=R_{g;[x_{i},x_{i+1}]}(\mathcal{P}'',\Xi)$, where the notation means exactly what you think and $g=f-f(\xi_{i+1})$ and $\mathcal{P}''=\{x_{i},y,x_{i+1}\}$. The maximum of $g$ is $M':=\max_{x\in[x_{i},x_{i+1}]}f(x)-f(\xi_{i+1})=0$ by choice of the $f(\xi_{\cdot})$. So, „by (a)“ $R_{g;[x_{i},x_{i+1}]}(\mathcal{P}'',\Xi)\leq M'\cdot(x_{i+1}-x_{i})=0$ and (b) follows. Btw. why denote it $\Xi_{M}$? Seems quite senseless to me.

Comment: Yes, the symbol $\Xi_{M}$ is quite weird, if not wrong. I'm the TA of the class, and I am required to write an solution for the students.

Comment: All the best putting up with the lecturer’s suboptimal choices!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to consider the Riemann sum of $f$ over partition $P''=\{x_i, y, x_{i+1}\} $ of $[x_i, x_{i+1}]$. By $(a) $ we have $$U(f, P'')\leq M_{i+1}(x_{i+1}-x_i)=f(\xi_{i+1})(x_{i+1}-x_i) $$ and adding terms corresponding to intervals $$[x_0,x_1],\dots,[x_{i-1},x_i],[x_{i+1},x_{i+2}],\dots, [x_{n-1},x_n]$$ to the above inequality we get $U(f, P') \leq U(f, P) $.

I have deliberately stayed away from the notation used in your image as it is not standard.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that if $P:=\{ \xi_i \}_{i=0}^n$ is a partition of $[a,b]$, and $\xi_j= \zeta_0 < \zeta_1<...< \zeta_{l_j}=\xi_{j+1}$, then by (a) you know that:

$\underset{x\in [\xi_j,\xi_{j+1}]}{\sup} f(x)\cdot (\xi_{j+1}-\xi_{j})\geq \underset{r=1}{\overset{l_j}{\sum}} \Bigg( \underset{x\in [\zeta^j_{r},\zeta^j_{r+1}]}{\sup} f(x)\cdot (\zeta^j_{r+1}-\zeta^j_{r})\Bigg)$

Considering $P'$ which is a refinement of $P$ given by $\xi_j=\zeta_0^j<....<\zeta_{l_j}^j=\xi_{j+1}$ for all $0\leq j\leq n-1$, then:

$U(f,P) = \underset{j=1}{\overset{n}{\sum}} \Bigg( \underset{x\in [\xi_j,\xi_{j+1}]}{\sup} f(x)\cdot (\xi_j-\xi_{j+1})\Bigg)\leq$

$\leq \underset{j=1}{\overset{n}{\sum}} \Bigg( \underset{r=1}{\overset{l_j}{\sum}} \Big( \underset{x\in [\zeta^j_{r},\zeta^j_{r+1}]}{\sup} f(x)\cdot (\zeta^j_{r+1}-\zeta^j_{r})\Big) \Bigg)=U(f,P')$

Comment: Yes, that would be the sensible and natural way to prove that approximations are monotone in refinements. The OP knows this, I imagine, as do we all. The problem was to figure out how to „use (a)“ to prove (b).

Comment: @Keen-ameteur: You show that $U(f,P)\leq U(f,P')$?

Comment: Yes which I thought was the OP asked about. Though now it appears I might've misunderstood.